# How much time will it take to review ON HOLD questions?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, policy, specific-question

I have asked a [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/117391/find-out-the-dimension-of-fracab) before 3 days and it was put on hold. After that i have done all the required editing in the question and also put the comment but till now it haven't been reviewed.

I think after edit, the question is up to the standard because before editing question had got -2 votes but now after editing it has got 3 votes up

I hope the question will not be closed!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your post was [already reviewed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/46001), with a unanimous decision to keep closed.

There are still things to be improved, read the homework policy carefully. The summary up top captures the problem with your question well:

> It's not enough to just show your work and ask where you went wrong. If you just need someone to check your work, you can always seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher. As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on

On holded questions are no different from closed questions, the wording switches over automatically in five days. There is no actual difference between the two.

Comment: When i tried myself solving the problem i was able to do till what i have shown but when i was stuck i asked on physics stack exchange, which i think normally every body does. I thought that i was stuck due to some small mistake that's why i  have written "i don't know whether i am correct or not." So i have not only asked this question for checking it whether it is correct or not but i have asked it to help me in solving the remaining problem.

Comment: @Freddy Yes, and if you look at the policy we don't help with stuff like that.

Answer (score 3):

Once edited, questions that are `on-hold` are put into the [Review queue](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review) for reopening. It takes 5 people with reputation greater than 3,000 to accept a re-open. You can find more information [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions)

Note that your question *still* asks us to check your work for you, which is [not something we do here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange). It could be that *because* of this styled question, no one seems to want to re-open your question (as you have zero re-open nominations on your question).